# TinyMCE 5 - Display only first word in text area and hide structure

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using `tinymce 5` to add a synonym to a word:

[image]

I am adding the code like the following - `@addSynonym("Mike"," John"," Teresa")` - as I am using a template template language in the background that has the `@addSynonym()`-method and chooses randomly a word.

I would like to only display the first word in the text editor and marked with yellow.

Like that:

`<p>Hello, <span style="background-color: yellow;">Mike!</span></p>`

[image]

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

    <script>
        var dialogConfig =  {
            title: 'Add synonym',
            body: {
                type: 'panel',
                items: [
                    {
                        type: 'input',
                        name: 'synonymData',
                        label: 'Enter synonyms comma seperated'
                    }
                ]
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    type: 'cancel',
                    name: 'closeButton',
                    text: 'Cancel'
                },
                {
                    type: 'submit',
                    name: 'submitButton',
                    text: 'Submit',
                    primary: true
                }
            ],
            initialData: {
                synonymData: 'synonym1, synonym2, synonym3',
            },
            onSubmit: function (api) {
                var data = api.getData();
                var dataArr = data.synonymData.split(',');
                var stringData = dataArr.join('\",\"')

                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '@addSynonym(\"' + stringData + '\")');
                api.close();
            }
        };

        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            plugins: "code",
            toolbar: ['dialog-example-btn', 'code'],
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.ui.registry.addButton('dialog-example-btn', {
                    text: 'Add synonym',
                    onAction: function () {
                        editor.windowManager.open(dialogConfig)
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions how to implement this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE is (at its core) just rendering the HTML you pass to the editor.  If you want to see one thing visually but hold on to other data you would have to find some way to transform your code to get the visual outcome you want.

Perhaps you could use data attributes to hold the "real" data and simply show what you want?  For a rough example:

```
<span data-function="addSynonym" data-options="['Mike', 'John', 'Theresa']">
    <span style="background-color: yellow;">Mike</span>
</span>
```

This would allow you to not lose the actual data but still have it render as you like.  When the data is extracted from TinyMCE to be stored you would just reverse the process and recreate the code you need for later processing.